# python3-pip does not install Django

Tags: python, python3, pip

I tried to install Django with python3-pip
When I run

`pip3 install Django` or `sudo pip3 install Django`

It gives this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/home/amir/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/home/amir/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "/home/amir/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3018, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/home/amir/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3004, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/amir/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3046, in _initialize_master_working_set
    dist.activate(replace=False)
  File "/home/amir/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2578, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "/home/amir/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2152, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "/home/amir/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2092, in _handle_ns
    _rebuild_mod_path(path, packageName, module)
  File "/home/amir/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2121, in _rebuild_mod_path
    orig_path.sort(key=position_in_sys_path)
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

what can I do?!

Comment: Why don't you try `sudo pip3 install Django` I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: i use sudo but makes no difference

Comment: can you post the output please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use pip3 to install Django in Ubuntu 16.04 and later releases because Django is in the default repositories. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install python3-django
```

If you want to install Django using pip3 anyway, you should update pip3 to the latest version in order for pip3 to be able to install Django and its dependencies. Run these commands:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip  
sudo python3 -m pip install django
```

You can verify that the installation was successful by typing:

```
django-admin --version
```